Is it possible to lazily compute rhymes for a given word, in a somewhat memory and compute optimized way, or is it impossible?
Overview
I have a TypeScript module RhymeDictionary.ts which imports ClusterGraph.ts. The ClusterGraph is used to take as input a bunch of feature vectors for individual consonants, and create a graph structure out of it. It would generate data like this:
Graph-based Clustering Result:
Node: p
  Members: p
  Connections:
    - p+b (similarity: 0.950)
    - p+b+m (similarity: 0.900)

Node: b
  Members: b
  Connections:
    - p+b (similarity: 0.950)
    - b+m (similarity: 0.920)

Node: p+b
  Members: p, b
  Connections:
    - p (similarity: 0.950)
    - b (similarity: 0.950)
    - p+b+m (similarity: 0.925)

Node: m
  Members: m
  Connections:
    - b+m (similarity: 0.920)
    - p+b+m (similarity: 0.900)

Node: b+m
  Members: b, m
  Connections:
    - b (similarity: 0.920)
    - m (similarity: 0.920)
    - p+b+m (similarity: 0.910)

Node: p+b+m
  Members: p, b, m
  Connections:
    - p (similarity: 0.900)
    - p+b (similarity: 0.925)
    - b+m (similarity: 0.910)

// ... (more nodes and connections)

// and for clusters too:
Node: rks
  Members: r, k, s
  Connections:
    - r (similarity: 0.823)
    - k (similarity: 0.801)
    - s (similarity: 0.789)
    - ks (similarity: 0.856)

Node: ngks
  Members: n, g, k, s
  Connections:
    - n (similarity: 0.712)
    - g (similarity: 0.735)
    - k (similarity: 0.768)
    - s (similarity: 0.703)
    - ng (similarity: 0.821)
    - ks (similarity: 0.843)

This ClusterGraph.ts is used by RhymeDictionary.ts. In the current implementation of RhymeDictionary.ts (below), it first generates the cluster graph from all the individual consonants and consonant clusters. Then when you call dictionary.search(word), it converts the word to phonemes (assume sound/consonant representation of word). Then it calls dictionary.index(phonemes), and that is where the magic happens.
In dictionary.index(phonemes), it does this (very short):
// get all phoneme representations of all words...
const phonemeSequences = Array.from(this.phonemesToWords.keys())

// Build global similarity index
const similarities = []
for (let j = 0; j < phonemeSequences.length; j++) {
  const similarity = this.calculateSequenceSimilarity(
    inputPhonemes,
    phonemeSequences[j],
  )
  similarities.push([phonemeSequences[j], similarity])
}

// return words sorted by similarity
similarities.sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1])

The details are in what it does inside calculateSequenceSimilarity. The nested calls are basically:

calculateSequenceSimilarity (for an input phoneme, against all possible words in the dictionary)
createAlignmentMatrix (for each pair of words as phonemes, comparing the input to the dictionary list of phonemes)
calculatePhonemeOrClusterSimilarity (populates each cell of matrix)
calculateClusterSimilarity (for two consonant clusters, or just use the cluster graph unit values for getting the two vectors)
findMostSimilarCluster (when dealing with clusters)
calculateSimilarity (called for each cluster compared with input phoneme. This is just a cosineSimilarity implementation)

Problem
The problem I'm facing right now is that the dictionary.index(phonemes) function is called every time search is called. If there are let's say 10 million words in the dictionary (could be as little as 10k words up to 100 million words let's say), then on every HTTP request it is iterating through 10 million words and running these complicated calculations against the input. This is very costly and slow. (Though I haven't run benchmarks yet, but I would guess it takes a few seconds of blocking code evaluation for each input).
Current Solution
My current solution to this is to cache the results (at least the first 10k highest scoring results, for each possible input phoneme sequence, which means every possible ending rhyme sequence, which we limit to 2 or 3 syllables for practical purposes), in a SQL DB. And to also store in Redis whether or not the calculation was attempted previously, returning:

false if never tried the query before.
true if the query was tried, but no results were found (scoring above a certain threshold let's say).

So first it requests from the SQL DB, and if empty, checks Redis, and if false there, it performs the full scan in memory in the .index function. (All words are stored in memory as well, for this purpose).
So basically, I am just lazily-computing the rhyme results for each input.
But this is subject to spamming, for one. A hacker could just iterate through all possible phoneme strings, and our system would store in the SQL DB and Redis a ton of data.... How can this be avoided?
Question
How can we create an in-memory data structure from the "phoneme list" (all 10 million phoneme strings), and have it be queryable at runtime to find the top-scoring rhyme matches, according to the similarity calculation functions?
Is it possible to create some sort of Trie out of the possible phonetic similarity matches, without precomputing all scores? Is there any possible solution that will allow not storing the cross-product of scored phonemes to phonemes?
I don't necessarily even need working code in the answer to this question. I just need to know (1) if it's possible to solve this so it doesn't require an explosion of DB records to cache all combinations (and also not an explosion of in-memory structures either), and (2) if it is possible, what algorithms and/or data structures I can further look into to craft a solution from?
Source Code
Finally, here is the full source code for the 2 modules this question depends on, the ClusterGraph.ts (for computing feature vectors for the consonants/clusters), and the RhymeDictionary.ts which uses ClusterGraph to find most similar rhymes to a given input word/phoneme string.
Here is my ./ClusterGraph module:
const VECTOR_DIMENSION = 6

const stringSimWeight = 0.2
const vectorSimWeight = 0.4
const sequenceSimWeight = 0.4

// Define types
export type Feature = number

export type FeatureVector = Array<Feature>

export type PhoneticUnit = {
  id: string
  vector: FeatureVector
}

export type ConsonantCluster = {
  id: string
  phonemes: Array<string>
  vector: FeatureVector
}

export type ClusterGraph = {
  clusters: Map<string, ConsonantCluster>
  edges: Array<ClusterEdge>
}

export type ClusterEdge = {
  from: string
  to: string
  weight: number
}

// Define constants (keep your existing PHONETIC_UNITS constant)

// Helper functions (keep your existing helper functions like jaroWinklerSimilarity, cosineSimilarity, etc.)

function calculateClusterVector(
  phonemes: Array<string>,
  units: Map<string, FeatureVector>,
): FeatureVector {
  const vectors = phonemes.map(p => units.get(p)!)
  return combineVectors(vectors)
}

function combineVectors(vectors: Array<FeatureVector>): FeatureVector {
  const result = new Array(VECTOR_DIMENSION).fill(0)
  for (const vec of vectors) {
    for (let i = 0; i < vec.length; i++) {
      result[i] += vec[i]
    }
  }
  return result.map(v => v / vectors.length)
}

function calculateSequenceSimilarity(
  seq1: Array<string>,
  seq2: Array<string>,
): number {
  const longerSeq = seq1.length >= seq2.length ? seq1 : seq2
  const shorterSeq = seq1.length < seq2.length ? seq1 : seq2

  // Longest Common Subsequence (LCS)
  const lcsMatrix: Array<Array<number>> = Array(shorterSeq.length + 1)
    .fill(null)
    .map(() => Array<number>(longerSeq.length + 1).fill(0))

  for (let i = 1; i <= shorterSeq.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 1; j <= longerSeq.length; j++) {
      if (shorterSeq[i - 1] === longerSeq[j - 1]) {
        lcsMatrix[i]![j] = lcsMatrix[i - 1]![j - 1]! + 1
      } else {
        lcsMatrix[i]![j] = Math.max(
          lcsMatrix[i - 1]![j]!,
          lcsMatrix[i]![j - 1]!,
        )
      }
    }
  }

  const lcsLength = lcsMatrix[shorterSeq.length]![longerSeq.length]!

  // Position-based weighting
  let positionWeight = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < shorterSeq.length; i++) {
    if (shorterSeq[i] === longerSeq[i]) {
      positionWeight += 1 / (i + 1)
    }
  }
  positionWeight /= shorterSeq.length

  // Combine LCS and position-based similarity
  const lcsSimilarity = lcsLength / longerSeq.length
  const combinedSimilarity = (lcsSimilarity + positionWeight) / 2

  return combinedSimilarity
}

function jaroWinklerSimilarity(s1: string, s2: string): number {
  // Implement Jaro-Winkler similarity
  // This is a simplified version; a full implementation would be more complex
  const maxLength = Math.max(s1.length, s2.length)
  const matchDistance = Math.floor(maxLength / 2) - 1
  const s1Matches: Array<boolean> = new Array(s1.length).fill(false)
  const s2Matches: Array<boolean> = new Array(s2.length).fill(false)
  let matches = 0

  for (let i = 0; i < s1.length; i++) {
    const start = Math.max(0, i - matchDistance)
    const end = Math.min(i + matchDistance + 1, s2.length)

    for (let j = start; j < end; j++) {
      if (!s2Matches[j] && s1[i] === s2[j]) {
        s1Matches[i] = true
        s2Matches[j] = true
        matches++
        break
      }
    }
  }

  if (matches === 0) {
    return 0
  }

  let transpositions = 0
  let j = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < s1.length; i++) {
    if (s1Matches[i]) {
      while (!s2Matches[j]) {
        j++
      }
      if (s1[i] !== s2[j]) {
        transpositions++
      }
      j++
    }
  }

  const jaroSimilarity =
    (matches / s1.length +
      matches / s2.length +
      (matches - transpositions / 2) / matches) /
    3

  const prefixLength = Math.min(4, Math.min(s1.length, s2.length))
  let commonPrefix = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < prefixLength; i++) {
    if (s1[i] === s2[i]) {
      commonPrefix++
    } else {
      break
    }
  }

  return jaroSimilarity + commonPrefix * 0.1 * (1 - jaroSimilarity)
}

function calculateClusterSimilarity(
  cluster1: ConsonantCluster,
  cluster2: ConsonantCluster,
): number {
  const stringSimilarity = jaroWinklerSimilarity(
    cluster1.id,
    cluster2.id,
  )
  const vectorSimilarity = cosineSimilarity(
    cluster1.vector,
    cluster2.vector,
  )
  const sequenceSimilarity = calculateSequenceSimilarity(
    cluster1.phonemes,
    cluster2.phonemes,
  )

  return (
    stringSimWeight * stringSimilarity +
    vectorSimWeight * vectorSimilarity +
    sequenceSimWeight * sequenceSimilarity
  )
}

function cosineSimilarity(a: FeatureVector, b: FeatureVector): number {
  const length = Math.max(a.length, b.length)
  let dotProduct = 0
  let normA = 0
  let normB = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    const aVal = a[i] || 0
    const bVal = b[i] || 0
    dotProduct += aVal * bVal
    normA += aVal * aVal
    normB += bVal * bVal
  }
  return dotProduct / (Math.sqrt(normA) * Math.sqrt(normB))
}

export default function buildConsonantClusterGraph({
  clusters,
  units,
  similarityThreshold,
}: {
  clusters: Array<Array<string>>
  units: Map<string, FeatureVector>
  similarityThreshold: number
}): ClusterGraph {
  const graph: ClusterGraph = {
    clusters: new Map(),
    edges: [],
  }

  // Create ConsonantCluster objects for each specified cluster
  clusters.forEach(phonemes => {
    const id = phonemes.join('')
    const cluster: ConsonantCluster = {
      id,
      phonemes,
      vector: calculateClusterVector(phonemes, units),
    }
    graph.clusters.set(id, cluster)
  })

  // Calculate similarities between clusters
  const clusterList = Array.from(graph.clusters.values())
  for (let i = 0; i < clusterList.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < clusterList.length; j++) {
      const similarity = calculateClusterSimilarity(
        clusterList[i]!,
        clusterList[j]!,
      )
      if (similarity >= similarityThreshold) {
        graph.edges.push({
          from: clusterList[i]!.id,
          to: clusterList[j]!.id,
          weight: similarity,
        })
      }
    }
  }

  return graph
}

And here is the ./RhymeDictionary which imports ClusterGraph:
import buildConsonantClusterGraph, {
  ClusterGraph,
  ConsonantCluster,
} from "./ClusterGraph";

export const VECTOR_DIMENSION = 6

type PhonemeSequence = string

type Word = string

type PhoneticFeatureVector = Array<number>

export default class RhymeDictionary {
  private wordToPhonemes: Map<Word, PhonemeSequence>

  private phonemesToWords: Map<PhonemeSequence, Set<Word>>

  private similarityIndex: Map<
    PhonemeSequence,
    Array<[PhonemeSequence, number]>
  >

  private units: Map<string, PhoneticFeatureVector>

  private clusterGraph: ClusterGraph

  constructor({
    units,
    clusters,
    similarityThreshold = 0.2,
  }: {
    units: Map<string, PhoneticFeatureVector>
    clusters: Array<Array<string>>
    similarityThreshold: number
  }) {
    this.units = units
    this.wordToPhonemes = new Map()
    this.phonemesToWords = new Map()
    this.similarityIndex = new Map()
    this.clusterGraph = buildConsonantClusterGraph({
      clusters,
      units,
      similarityThreshold,
    })
  }

  index({
    inputPhonemes,
  }: {
    inputPhonemes: string
  }): Array<[PhonemeSequence, number]> {
    const phonemeSequences = Array.from(this.phonemesToWords.keys())

    // Build global similarity index
    const similarities: Array<[PhonemeSequence, number]> = []
    for (let j = 0; j < phonemeSequences.length; j++) {
      const similarity = this.calculateSequenceSimilarity(
        inputPhonemes,
        phonemeSequences[j]!,
      )
      similarities.push([phonemeSequences[j]!, similarity])
    }

    similarities.sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1])

    return similarities
  }

  async search({
    word,
    page,
    pageSize,
  }: {
    word: Word
    page: number
    pageSize: number
  }): Promise<{ rhymes: Array<Word>; totalCount: number }> {
    const phonemes = this.wordToPhonemes.get(word)
    if (!phonemes) {
      return { rhymes: [], totalCount: 0 }
    }

    let similarPhonemes: Array<[PhonemeSequence, number]> =
      this.index({
        inputPhonemes: phonemes,
      })

    const rhymes: Array<Word> = []
    let totalCount = 0
    const startIndex = (page - 1) * pageSize

    for (const [currentPhonemes, _] of similarPhonemes) {
      const words = Array.from(
        this.phonemesToWords.get(currentPhonemes) || [],
      )
      for (const rhyme of words) {
        if (rhyme !== word) {
          if (totalCount >= startIndex && rhymes.length < pageSize) {
            rhymes.push(rhyme)
          }
          totalCount++
        }
      }

      if (rhymes.length === pageSize) {
        break
      }
    }

    return { rhymes, totalCount }
  }

  private calculateSequenceSimilarity(
    seq1: PhonemeSequence,
    seq2: PhonemeSequence,
  ): number {
    const phonemes1 = seq1.split(' ')
    const phonemes2 = seq2.split(' ')
    const matrix = this.createAlignmentMatrix(phonemes1, phonemes2)
    const alignmentScore = matrix[phonemes1.length]![phonemes2.length]!

    // Normalize the score by the length of the longer sequence
    const maxLength = Math.max(phonemes1.length, phonemes2.length)
    return alignmentScore / maxLength
  }

  private createAlignmentMatrix(
    seq1: Array<string>,
    seq2: Array<string>,
  ): Array<Array<number>> {
    const matrix: Array<Array<number>> = Array(seq1.length + 1)
      .fill(null)
      .map(() => Array<number>(seq2.length + 1).fill(0))

    // Initialize first row and column
    for (let i = 1; i <= seq1.length; i++) {
      matrix[i]![0] = matrix[i - 1]![0]! - 1
    }
    for (let j = 1; j <= seq2.length; j++) {
      matrix[0]![j] = matrix[0]![j - 1]! - 1
    }

    // Fill the matrix
    for (let i = 1; i <= seq1.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 1; j <= seq2.length; j++) {
        const match = this.calculatePhonemeOrClusterSimilarity(
          seq1[i - 1]!,
          seq2[j - 1]!,
        )
        matrix[i]![j] = Math.max(
          matrix[i - 1]![j - 1]! + match,
          matrix[i - 1]![j]! - 1,
          matrix[i]![j - 1]! - 1,
        )
      }
    }

    return matrix
  }

  private calculatePhonemeOrClusterSimilarity(
    p1: string,
    p2: string,
  ): number {
    // Check if p1 and p2 are clusters
    const cluster1 = this.clusterGraph.clusters.get(p1)
    const cluster2 = this.clusterGraph.clusters.get(p2)

    if (cluster1 && cluster2) {
      // If both are clusters, use cluster similarity
      return this.calculateClusterSimilarity(
        cluster1.vector,
        cluster2.vector,
      )
    } else {
      // If not clusters, calculate similarity based on phonetic feature vectors
      const vec1 =
        this.units.get(p1) ||
        new Array<number>(VECTOR_DIMENSION).fill(0)
      const vec2 =
        this.units.get(p2) ||
        new Array<number>(VECTOR_DIMENSION).fill(0)
      return this.calculateSimilarity(vec1, vec2)
    }
  }

  private calculateSimilarity(
    a: PhoneticFeatureVector,
    b: PhoneticFeatureVector,
  ): number {
    let dotProduct = 0
    let normA = 0
    let normB = 0

    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      dotProduct += a[i]! * b[i]!
      normA += a[i]! * a[i]!
      normB += b[i]! * b[i]!
    }

    return dotProduct / (Math.sqrt(normA) * Math.sqrt(normB))
  }

  private calculateClusterSimilarity(
    a: PhoneticFeatureVector,
    b: PhoneticFeatureVector,
  ): number {
    // Find the most similar clusters for vectors a and b
    const clusterA = this.findMostSimilarCluster(a)
    const clusterB = this.findMostSimilarCluster(b)

    if (clusterA && clusterB) {
      // Check if there's an edge between these clusters
      const edge = this.clusterGraph.edges.find(
        e =>
          (e.from === clusterA.id && e.to === clusterB.id) ||
          (e.from === clusterB.id && e.to === clusterA.id),
      )

      if (edge) {
        return edge.weight
      }
    }

    // If no cluster similarity found, calculate cosine similarity
    return this.calculateSimilarity(a, b)
  }

  private findMostSimilarCluster(
    vector: PhoneticFeatureVector,
  ): ConsonantCluster | undefined {
    let mostSimilarCluster: ConsonantCluster | undefined
    let highestSimilarity = -1

    for (const cluster of this.clusterGraph.clusters.values()) {
      const similarity = this.calculateSimilarity(
        vector,
        cluster.vector,
      )

      if (similarity > highestSimilarity) {
        highestSimilarity = similarity
        mostSimilarCluster = cluster
      }
    }

    return mostSimilarCluster
  }
}

Note, without getting into the weeds of the feature encoding, there are 6 features per consonant here. So the vector is 6 long (ranging from 0 to 1 in decimal values). The features are things like "position in mouth", "voicing", "modificiation like aspiration, etc.", "duration", "form like plosive, nasal, etc.", etc.. You can assume the phoneme encoding is basically the CMU pronunciation dictionary encoding, which is 1+ ascii symbols per sound, separated by spaces.
Here are two hypothetical examples of words with their CMU pronunciations (0 means unstressed, 1 means stressed, but irrelevant for this question):

"computer":

CMU Pronunciation: K AH0 M P Y UW1 T ER0
Phonetic Breakdown:

K: /k/ as in "cat"
AH0: /ə/ as in "sofa" (unstressed)
M: /m/ as in "man"
P: /p/ as in "pat"
Y: /j/ as in "yes"
UW1: /uː/ as in "food" (stressed)
T: /t/ as in "top"
ER0: /ɚ/ as in "butter" (unstressed)




"language":

CMU Pronunciation: L AE1 N G W IH0 JH
Phonetic Breakdown:

L: /l/ as in "lip"
AE1: /æ/ as in "cat" (stressed)
N: /n/ as in "nose"
G: /g/ as in "go"
W: /w/ as in "we"
IH0: /ɪ/ as in "bit" (unstressed)
JH: /dʒ/ as in "judge"





Also note, I am not dealing with vowels yet (though vowels will also have 6 features....). So just assume we are dealing with consonant strings for purposes of this questions, to keep things a little more simple.

Please [edit] this to be a [mre] that focuses on the algorithmic issue you're facing instead of the full use case. Right now this is a huge amount of code with lots of details about phonetics that probably don't affect the approach one might take to store/query the data. It's hard to see through these details to the basic computing/caching issue.
